# Replace null bytes

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I want to replace null bystes from string. But after replacing of the null bytes \u0000 of the string

```
let data = {"tet":HelloWorld.\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"}
let test = JSON.parse(data).tet.replace("\u0000", "");
```

I am getting always following value:

```
 HelloWorld.[][][][]
```

This are not array brackets or something like that.

I just need the value HelloWorld. How can I do this?

Ok, the solution was to replace all bytes.

```
.replace(new RegExp("\u0000", "g"), "");
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` accepts a _string_ as input. Did you mean to use `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: What? You want the value `HelloWorld.` but you're only getting `HelloWorld.`? What?

Comment: @HerrDerb It's just that your browser won't show that unicode character. '\u0000' is the null character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normal string replace only replaces the first occurence.

But by using a regex with a **g**lobal flag it'll replace all occurences.

Example snippet :

```js
console.log("bar bar".replace("bar","foo"));
console.log("bar bar".replace(/bar/g,"foo"));

let data = {"test":"HelloWorld.\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"};

console.log("before: " + data.test);
console.log("before (stringified): " + JSON.stringify(data.test));

// removing all the NULL unicode characters
data.test = data.test.replace(/\u0000/g,'');

console.log("after  (stringified): " + JSON.stringify(data.test));
```